# Attempted to read or write protected memory - image manipulation

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have this code;

```
BitmapData bdBackground = Background.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, Background.Width,
    Background.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, Background.PixelFormat);
BitmapData bdForeground = videoFrame.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, videoFrame.Width,
    videoFrame.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, videoFrame.PixelFormat);

unsafe
{
    for (int x = 0; x < videoFrame.Width; x++)
    {
        byte* columnBackground = (byte*)bdBackground.Scan0 + (x * bdBackground.Stride);
        byte* columnForeground = (byte*)bdForeground.Scan0 + (x * bdForeground.Stride);

        for (int y = 0; y < videoFrame.Height; y++)
        {
             if (columnBackground[x * pixelSize] == columnForeground[x * pixelSize])
             {
                  columnForeground[x] = 0;
             }
        }
    }
}
Background.UnlockBits(bdBackground);
videoFrame.UnlockBits(bdForeground);
```

it gives me error;

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

in `if (columnBackground[x * pixelSize] == columnForeground[x * pixelSize])`

what is the reason for that? I take this code from [here](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=5715&lngWId=10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never use the `y` variable when accessing the bitmap array.  You should be multiplying `y` by the `Stride` instead of `x`.  Then add `x * pixelSize` like you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to understand how an image is stored in an array.
Images "usually in most APIs" are row major, meaning they are stored row by row (usually in a one dimensional array).
To loop through a row major image (walk the pixels), the outer loop is usually from 0 to height, and the inner from 0 to width. This makes the loops easier to read, and increases cache hits.
Stride is a very important concept, it represents the number of bytes needed for each row, and is not necessarily equal to the width*bytes per pixel, as padding for alignment reasons is usually present.

Stride is used to access a new row, for example, if I want to access the third row:
`third_Row = 3 * image_stride`;
If you want to access the 10th pixel of the third row, you just add (`10 * bytes per pixel`) to third_Row:
`third_Row_Tenth_Pixel = 3 * image_stride + 10 * Bytes_per_pixel`

**NOTE: please mark the above does not apply to any image where bits per pixel are lower than 8, usually 4, 2, or 1 are used.**

What you are doing is the reverse, you are multiplying the column number by the stride, instead of the row number, effectively, stepping out of the range of the image.

In short, reverse the x and y loops, making the y one contain the x one(for reasons of increasing cache hits):

```
unsafe
{
    for (int y = 0; y < videoFrame.Height; y++)
    {
        byte* columnBackground = (byte*)bdBackground.Scan0 + (y * bdBackground.Stride);
        byte* columnForeground = (byte*)bdForeground.Scan0 + (y * bdForeground.Stride);

        for (int x = 0; x < videoFrame.Width; x++)
        {
             if (columnBackground[x * pixelSize] == columnForeground[x * pixelSize])
             {
                  columnForeground[x] = 0;
             }
        }
    }
}
Background.UnlockBits(bdBackground);
videoFrame.UnlockBits(bdForeground);
```